# How to p4 shelve multiple files

Tags: perforce, shelve

I have two files I tried to shelve with a one-liner that did not work.
How do I shelve multiple files? Below is what I tried.

p4 edit uv5_ni_llp_rcv_crd_m.sv uv5_ni_llp_rcv_crd_vc_m.sv

Made some updates before shelving these files.

p4 shelve uv5_ni_llp_rcv_crd_m.sv uv5_ni_llp_rcv_crd_vc_m.sv

Usage: shelve [ files ]
Missing/wrong number of arguments.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

`p4 shelve [files]` takes only a single `files` argument, which can include a wildcard.  Try this:

```
p4 edit uv5_ni_llp_rcv_crd_m.sv uv5_ni_llp_rcv_crd_vc_m.sv
p4 shelve ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Running "p4 shelve" without any arguments will "shelve" all open files.

Note well: You can still edit which files will be shelved.
The command will open a changelist description page in editor.
The description has a list of files which you can edit.
You can remove files from list, which you do not want to shelve/save.